# Image Viewer Not Showing PNGs?

Tags: eog

I can't view PNGs using the image viewer, it shows up as a transparent square. The image opens fine in GIMP. Other files such as JPEGs show up in image viewer. I've tried uninstall/reinstalling it and the problem still persists. It's a bit buggy in general, as the minimize and close buttons at the top right disappear when I hover over them. The image viewer was working fine last week.

[Screenshot of image viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI6dI.png)

Comment: I suggest to change an image viewer, because the default image viewer "eye of gnome" (eog) is sometimes buggy and has only limited functions. I recommend "gthumb", which is also in the default repository.

Comment: "*The image viewer was working fine last week*" - retrace your steps.  What have you done since it was last working?